# Scipy Optimisation Crashes with Pandas Error

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

i am running pandas 0.20 and scipy 0.17.1. When I run the optimization:

```
res = minimize(run_opt, x0, method='COBYLA', constraints=cons, tol=None, callback=None, options={'disp': True, 'catol': 0.0002, 'maxiter': 1000, 'rhobeg': 1.0})
```

and

```
cons = ({'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda t: t})
```

I get the following error on a pandas query that runs in the function as below:

```
  File "H:script_1.py", line 159, in Fun_3
    Res_Table[i] = btst.query('Var_1=='+str(i+1))

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2116, in query
    res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2186, in eval
    return _eval(expr, inplace=inplace, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\eval.py", line 262, in eval
    truediv=truediv)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 727, in __init__
    self.terms = self.parse()

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 744, in parse
    return self._visitor.visit(self.expr)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 313, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 319, in visit_Module
    return self.visit(expr, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 313, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 322, in visit_Expr
    return self.visit(node.value, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 313, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 644, in visit_Compare
    return self.visit(binop)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 313, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 416, in visit_BinOp
    op, op_class, left, right = self._maybe_transform_eq_ne(node)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 354, in _maybe_transform_eq_ne
    left = self.visit(node.left, side='left')

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 313, in visit
    return visitor(node, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 430, in visit_Name
    return self.term_type(node.id, self.env, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\ops.py", line 58, in __init__
    self._value = self._resolve_name()

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\ops.py", line 75, in _resolve_name
    res = self.env.resolve(self.local_name, is_local=self.is_local)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\scope.py", line 192, in resolve
    raise compu.ops.UndefinedVariableError(key, is_local
```

Where Var_1 is a Column Header with which I filter a Pandas DataFrame. The error occurs very frequently but not at a predictable moment. Important to note that if the function "run_opt" is executed outside of the scipy optimization environment, it executes just fine.

Could it be a bug or am I clueless as to how to use scipy? Any input will be massively appreciated!

Comment: It is hard to know what is going on without seeing a [minimal, complete and verifiable exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  My guess is you are using Pandas DataFrames with SciPy functions.  Don't do that.  SciPy knows nothing about DataFrames, and DataFrames don't always act like numpy arrays.  Convert your data to numpy arrays before handing it off to SciPy code.  (Sometimes just tacking on `.values`--e.g. `df.values`--is sufficient to convert the DataFrame `df` to an array.)

Comment: I guess so. I have a function ("run_opt") that Scipy runs which contains some lines that use Pandas (the df.query function). I guess I will try to convert  everything to numpy and try again. Thanks for the help!